# Raw character literal

Tags: c++, c++11, character, string-literals

I don't know if I've missed something or it really doesn't exists. In the C++11 standard the [Raw string literals](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings) were added:

```
string s = "\\w\\\\\\w"; // I hope I got that right
string s = R"(\w\\\w)";  // I'm pretty sure I got that right
```

But all my attempts to use a Raw character literal have failed:

```
constexpr char bslash = R('\'); // error: missing terminating ' character
constexpr char bslash = R'(\)'; // error: 'R' was not declared in this scope
```

The second attempt is considered a multi-character constant! The only way I've found to use something similar to Raw character literal is:

```
constexpr char slash = *R"(\)"; // All Ok.
```

But I don't like this notation (dereferencing a string literal in order to store a copy of the first element) because is kind of confusing.

Well, what's the question?

- Did the Raw character literals exists? (I've not found nothing about them so I'm nearly sure that they don't)

  - If they exists: How I should write a Raw character literal?
  - If they don't exist: Why? Is there a reason to add Raw string literals but AVOID to add Raw character literals?

Comment: As good a reason as any: `char a = '\\'; // I'm pretty sure I got that right`

Comment: See e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2053.html#Raw-character-literals which says *"As a deliberate design choice, the proposal does not include raw character (as opposed to string) literals because there is no apparent need; escape sequences do not pose the same practical problems in character literals that they do in string-literals."*

Comment: @dyp that is an answer

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour clearly not, as it is in the comments.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk yes, I get it, say what you mean not mean what you say ;-) ... it should be an answer it addresses all the points.

Comment: @CássioRenan: As long as you never want a multi-character literal. Then you're back to `int a = '\\w\\\\\\w'; // is that right?`

Comment: Another fun raw character constant: `0[R"(\)"]`

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah, but when would you ever want to rely on implementation-defined behavior instead of manually computing the value?

Comment: @Columbo: Why does is matter whether or not I'd want to use them? My point was that they exist, so one shouldn't simply ignore them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It matters, because such peculiar code is not a convincing argument for introducing a core language change. And if people are actually making use of multichar-literals, it potentially breaks [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20ac732231c3d570). :o)

Comment: @Columbo: No, it doesn't matter whether I personally want to use them. It does matter that they exist, since as you say changing their behaviour could break code; which is why I pointed out their existence, and said that one shouldn't simply ignore them. I've no idea why you find that controversial, when as far as I can see we're in agreement.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sorry, I didn't mean *you* specifically. I meant that, because of the nature of multichar literals, the set of use cases for such a new feature is so sparse that it wouldn't really be beneficial enough to warrant a language change.

Comment: @dyp I agree with ShafikYaghmour about that coment of yours could be marked as an answer to my question... Indeed it points to what I was looking for: A rationale for avoid Raw character literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposal that introduced raw string literals in C++11 is, as far as I can tell, [N2442 - Raw and Unicode String Literals; Unified Proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2442.htm). It is based upon [N2146 - Raw String Literals (Revision 1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2146.html) by *Beman Dawes*, which contains a section about *raw character literals*:

> As a deliberate design choice, raw character (as opposed to string)
>   literals are not proposed because there is no apparent need; escape
>   sequences do not pose the same practical problems in character
>   literals that they do in string literals.
>
> The arguments in favor of raw character literals are symmetry and
>   error-reduction. Knowing that raw string-literals are allowed,
>   programmers are likely to assume raw character-literals are also
>   available. Indeed, a committee member inadvertently made that
>   assumption when reading a draft of this paper. Although the resulting
>   error is easy to fix, there is the argument that it is better to
>   eliminate the possibility of the error by providing raw
>   character-literals in the first place.
>
> I will be happy to provide proposed wording if the committee desires
>   to add raw character literals.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any discussion in the meeting minutes that mention any of the related proposals. It is likely though that the reason mentioned first paragraph lead to the current situation.

Comment: Interesting to note, one counter argument for including support for raw char literals include symmetry which is similar to the argument for unary `+`  which seems pretty reasonable. ++1